# strcpy() only storing last string

Tags: c

I want to store elements of an array containing strings to make it accessible via a shared memory segment. I am currently using strcpy(), but it is obviously only storing the last string in the array. How would I make it store all 4 strings in the array? Currently I can only choose which line I would like to send (e.g. the first line with the two loops below:

Here is my loop in the server program:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 1;j++){
            strcpy(mem,words);
}
```

and the client program:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
    printf("%s\n",mem);
}
```

here is the full server program:

```
int main() {
    const key_t key = 12345678;
    FILE *ptr_fp;
    char words[600][600];
    char *mem;
    int i = 0;  
    ptr_fp = fopen("words.txt","r");  

    int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(float)*8, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);

    if (shmid < 0) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    } 

    if (ptr_fp != NULL){
        while(fgets(words[i],600,ptr_fp )&& i <600){
            i++;
        }
    }

    mem = (char *)shmat(shmid,NULL,0);

    if(mem == (char *)-1){
        perror("shmat error\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        for(int j = 0; j < 1;j++){
            strcpy(mem,words);
        }
        printf("Memory is attached\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fyi, the order of your multipart boolean eval in your `fgets` loop is backward. the `i` check should be *first*.

Comment: Why do you have `sizeof(float)*8` as the size of the shared memory, when you're not storing floats in it?

Comment: ... and where are these _4 strings_ you mention in your question?

Comment: sorry, the strings are stored in words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a copy-paste mistake.

In this `while` loop, `i` gets updated.

```
 while(fgets(words[i],600,ptr_fp )&& i <600) {
     i++;
 }
```

In the `for` loop, `j` should be compared to `i` in the controlling expression, instead it is compared with `1`

```
 for(int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
     strcpy(mem,words);
 }
```

I think the above should be changed to:

```
 for(int j = 0, k = 0; j < i; j++) {
     strcpy((mem + k),words[j]); 
     k = k+ strlen(words[j]); 
}
```

Comment: When I change the for loop to your suggestion, it gets the first char from each line an then continues print out the remaining characters of the last line

Comment: Try the following and let me know: `for(int j = 0, k = 0; j < i; j++) {
     strcpy((mem + k),words[j]); k = strlen(words[j]);
 }`

Comment: That prints lines 1 and 4 four times, it misses out on lines 2/3. Could there be an issue with my loop in the client program: `for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){ printf("%s\n",mem);}` Thankyou for your help

Comment: Actually the statement should be `k += strlen(words[j]);`. At each iteration it should add to the previous length.